# Docker hangs on pull from private dockerhub

Tags: docker, dockerhub

on azure VM, it's running docker

C:\Users>docker version
Client:
 Version:      17.06.2-ee-6
 API version:  1.30
 Go version:   go1.8.3
 Git commit:   e75fdb8
 Built:        Mon Nov 27 22:46:09 2017
 OS/Arch:      windows/amd64

Server:
 Version:      17.06.2-ee-6
 API version:  1.30 (minimum version 1.24)
 Go version:   go1.8.3
 Git commit:   e75fdb8
 Built:        Mon Nov 27 22:55:16 2017
 OS/Arch:      windows/amd64
 Experimental: false

when pulling from a private repo on dockerhub, it hangs when extracting part of the image.

Using default tag: latest
latest: Pulling from tekitsoft/web
407ada6e90de: Already exists
3cb15ab58a2c: Already exists
e1cc03b9b8eb: Already exists
3a704066cde0: Already exists
e27752919d66: Already exists
0df844d28249: Already exists
6758300bb1c4: Already exists
ef9595e18bd2: Already exists
5818114c861e: Already exists
954374078cec: Extracting [==================================================>]  1.137kB/1.137kB
d006b9ffaa5e: Download complete
5509c7f07a81: Download complete
2fab1333a68c: Download complete
a98521f426f1: Download complete

does anybody else see if kind of issue on this version of docker?

Comment: Can you confirm that there is enough space in docker's home directory (by default it is root)

Comment: Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is F8CE-930B

 Directory of C:\Users\admin007

02/21/2018  05:50 PM    <DIR>          .
02/21/2018  05:50 PM    <DIR>          ..
02/21/2018  12:38 AM    <DIR>          .docker
01/12/2018  03:58 AM    <DIR>          3D Objects

               2 File(s)              0 bytes
              15 Dir(s)  24,127,725,568 bytes free

Comment: so there is 24G free space

Comment: toasted the vm and created a new one. don't want to waste time on this kind of issue.